# Xamgrid refresh or reapply filters

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamgrid

Is there some way to reapply the filter without having to reselect the filter? Especially when the underlying observable collection is changed? I seem to have records which don't match the filter condition after a while..

Comment: Have the same issue. It always occures when using XamGrid on a page, which will be navigated to later again. I guess, it receives a loaded event and therefore forgets all applied filters...

Answer (score 1):

The XamGrid doesn't have a method to refresh.  The INotifyCollectionChanged events are supposed to handle updating the grid accordingly.

You could try programmatically removing the current filters that are set and then readd them.  It's a little tough for me to know if this will solve your issue though as I don't have a sample that reproduces the issue.

You could also try deriving from ObservableCollection and implement a refresh method.  Inside the refresh method you could call OnCollectionChanged and pass in a Reset action.  This might refresh the XamGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the [InvalidateData](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/Silverlight/2015.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsSL5.Controls.Grids.XamGrid.v15.2~Infragistics.Controls.Grids.XamGrid~InvalidateData.html)  method of the XamGrid class - it is supposed to invalidate all data operations like grouping, sorting and filtering.